# Why does this switch statement not work?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I created a switch statement but everything seems to be falling into the default condition. If I rewrite this in an if/else format it works correctly. Can anyone explain why this is? Thanks!

Doesn't work:

```
 switch(delta){
    case (delta<10):
      xsmall++;
      break;
    case (delta>= 10 && delta< 50):
      small++;
      break;
    case (delta>= 50 && delta<250):
      med++;
      break;
    case (delta>= 250 && delta<1000):
      large++;
      break;
    case (delta>= 1000):
      xlarge++;
      break;
    default:
      unknown++;
  }
```

Works successfully:

```
if(delta<10)
    xsmall++;
else if(delta>= 10 && delta < 50)
    small++;
else if(delta >= 50 && delta < 250)
    med++;
else if(delta >= 250 && delta <1000)
    large++;
else if(delta >= 1000)
    xlarge++;
else
   unknown++;
```

Comment: You are switching on the number `delta` but have booleans in your `case` labels.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
 switch(true){
    case (delta<10):
      xsmall++;
      break;
    case (delta>= 10 && delta< 50):
      small++;
      break;
    case (delta>= 50 && delta<250):
      med++;
      break;
    case (delta>= 250 && delta<1000):
      large++;
      break;
    case (delta>= 1000):
      xlarge++;
      break;
    default:
      unknown++;
  }
```

**Reason:** You need to pass boolean to the switch statement as all your cases will return boolean and not a number

Comment: --Your code LOOKS good--we all know what you INTEND. BUT did you successfully compile and execute that code? Could we see the entire program? I'm  having trouble getting rid of *"Duplicate label `false`"* errors. I don't get one in the first case. And what about the "rule"(?) "case expressions must be constant expressions"?

Comment: Code doesn't compile at all unless we make `delta` `final`, which gets rid of first case error, but then we're back to "Duplicate label false".